# JavaScript Parsing a function parameter to a getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Hi guys I want to do something thing like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="Div(variable)"/>
<script>
function Div(data){
    var A=document.getElementsByClassName('title')[data];
    A.style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

But the code won't work...

Comment: What is this `variable`?

Comment: variable is a number, that is used to identify the class number

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you sure the value of `variable` is a valid index into the collection?

Comment: If you have elements with that class `title` and  `variable >= 0 && variable < elements.length` then that code should work as expected!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you're setting `variable` and demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the varibale to the  The nodes and it can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

```js
function Div(data){
    var A=document.getElementsByClassName('title')[data];
    A.style.display='block';
}
```

```css
div{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me"onclick="Div(0)"/>
<div class="title">Hello world </div>
```

Comment: Requests for more information should be comments. How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Barmar sry i did update my answer assuming that the OP think that he cant passe a variable to the node to access the class , however i dont understand the downvote why

Comment: Why don't you think you can pass a variable? It has to be a global variable, though.

Comment: @Barmar the op think he cant passe a variable not me , since he saids it dosent work

Comment: We should find out why he thinks that doesn't work, and fix that.

Comment: You're assuming rather than to answering a question.  Your main error is posting an answer to an unclear question.

Comment: @Ele I will edit my answear according to the OP needs when he provide more info , and since he accepted the answear i guess i did assume right

Comment: @Abdeslem Charif thanks a lot it work!!God bless you!

Comment: @A.Rossi no problem , but i still got down voted for trying to help